# Dynamically change pivots of an object

Tags: rigging, transforms, constraints

Is it possible to rotate one object (**A**) around another object's origin (**B**) without transforming **A**'s origin to **B**'s? I need this because I want to rotate **A** around several objects successively. I know this can be done with the "Follow Path" constraint, but it is a complicated method. Also note that the "Pivot" constraint can be used only once and cannot be changed dynamically (or at least I don't know how it does).

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand your project correctly a simple method would be to place an empty at B's origin and parent A to that and rotate the empty.  Move/transform the Empty from object to object when required.

Comment: You can generally parent an object to an empty placed at the desired center of rotation, though I don't know how to do it for several different points

Comment: Do you need the rotation for an animation?

Comment: @Edgel3D: And then I'll "clear parent + keep transformations" the empty and keyframe the location of **A**? It's a bit less parametric than I'd like, but ok. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the general solution to "dynamically change any constraint" which subsumes "dynamically change pivot". It's simple: Change the "Influence".

Flowchart:

1. Create (stack) as many pivot constraints as required and target them
   to the respective objects (or empties).
2. Set "Influence" of all the   pivots to "0" before creating any
   key-frames.
3. For the first rotation about (suppose) the x-axis, key-frame the
   x-rotation and set Influence to 1.
4. Scrub frames till **a**, rotate as required and key-frame x-rot.
5. Now to blend this with the second rotation, scrub a few (**k**)
   frames back till **a-k**, key-frame the first Pivot's Influence (now
   at 1) and also key-frame the second Pivot's Influence (at 0).
6. Scrub forward to **a+k** frame and switch the values of the  first
   and second Pivots' Influence; key-frame both.
7. Scrub frames and setup the second rotation as before (Step 4.), and so on.

I endorse this method over other simpler Transformation methods since this is parametric and has few dependencies.